# Linux javac command erroring on wildcard in classpath

Tags: java, linux, classpath, wildcard

I am running Windows 7 with Java version *1.6.0_31-b05* on my PC, and my computerlab's  network Linux (Fedora, possibly version 13) is running Java version *1.6.0_35-b10*.

I have a `C:\myproject` (et al) directory, with `src`, `lib`, and `bin` subdirectories.

- The `src` folder contains all of the source code in a tree structure, that corresponds to the java packages.
- The `lib` directory contains JAR files.

I have re-created the tree in Linux, under `../myproject` (et al).

- When I attempt to compile in DOS, from the `..\myproject\src` directory, with this command below, it works fine:

  ```
  javac -cp ".;../bin;../lib/*" -d ../bin org/unlv/schillerlab/motif_diversity/step02/*.java
  ```
- When I attempt to compile in Linux, from the `../myproject/src` directory, I get the message **incorrect classpath**: `../lib/*`:

  ```
  javac -cp ".:../bin:../lib/*" -d ../bin org/unlv/schillerlab/motif_diversity/step02/*.java
  ```

The computerlab network location is accessible from both DOS and Linux.  In Linux, I first created the `../myproject/src`, `../myproject/lib`, and `../myproject/bin` directories.  Then, in DOS, I copied the  necessary files from my `C` drive to `../myproject/src01` and `../myproject/lib01`.  Then, in Linux, I used the `cp -av` command to populate `src` and `lib` from `src01` and `lib01`, respectively.  Therefore, I don't think there is a Linux permissions problem.

In Linux, from the `../myproject/src` location, issuing `ls ../lib` shows that the  (sibling) `lib` directory does contain the JAR files.  I have also tried the Linux `javac` command with an absolute path to the `lib` directory; no joy.
Similarly, I tried removing the quote (`"`) marks from the `-cp` clause; no joy.

Could the problem be that I am running an old version of Fedora?  If not, does any one have a hypothesis as to what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

Wildcard expansion may behave differently on Linux than on Windows: In Unixlike systems, it is the shells duty to perform the wildcard expansion **before** the arguments are passed to the executable; on Windows its each programs own duty to do wildcard expansion (if at all). In doubt replace `javac` with `echo` to see how the wildcards are actually expanded! And you should rather use the `-sourcepath` option to `javac` to define the source location (Can't tell if this actually works, it must have been 10+ years since i last used that...)

Comment: echo ../lib/* does indeed list all of the jar files.  Also, given everything that I've read, + that the command works in Dos, I think that in the Linux javac command, specifying the jar file directory (i.e. ../lib/*) as part of the classpath parameter should work.

Comment: On Linux (at least in Bash), wildcard expansion doesn't happen inside of "".  Echo "../lib/*" will not do the same thing as echo ../lib/*   .  That said, it does look like either form should work, according to the documentation.  Are you running javac from your src/ directory?

Comment: So, the attempt in Linux, with the quote marks, _should_ (and does) fail.  Just to be careful, I just retried, without the quote marks:  

javac -cp .:../bin:../lib/* -d ../bin org/unlv/schillerlab/motif_diversity/step02/*.java 

The incorrect classpath: ../lib/* repsonse persists. 

Yes, I am running javac from my src directory.

Comment: My bad... I misread Sbodd's response: per this response, the attempt with quote marks should also succeed.  Anyway, both tries fail.